# Mysql Prepare Statement Multiple Insert

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to insert multiple insert entries using mysql prepare statement. However, it is not happening.

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 
'Insert into bookingdetails 
VALUES
(?,''2014-03-12'',''sl1'',3,''GA'',12.5,37.5),
(?,''2014-03-12'',''sl1'',3,''GA'',12.5,37.5)';
SET @a = 4;
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

The result is

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM  'Insert into bookingdetails  VALUES (?,''2014-03-12'',''sl1'',3,''GA'',12.5,37.5), (?,''2014-03-12'',''sl1'',3,''GA'',12.5,37.5)'

0 row(s) affected Statement prepared.
```

Please suggest.

The above issue has been resolved. I got other one.

Flow.

I'm passing one insert query from the PHP.

```
Insert into bm VALUES(?,'2014-03-11')
```

Formatting the above insert as per PREPARE STATEMENT friendly. var_bm variable is the IN parameter of stored_procedure with IN value as above insert from PHP.

```
set xbmquery=(select concat("'",replace(var_bm,"'", "\\'"),"\'\;"));

Output
'Insert into bm VALUES(?,\'2014-03-11\')';
```

Following is the prepare statement inside the stored procedure.

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'Select xbmquery';
SET @a = 16;
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

The data is not getting inserted in the respective table. 
Please let me know where my mistake.

Comment: why have u used (''2014-03-12'') ? I mean why double quote try with single quote

Comment: PREPARE stmt1 FROM 
'Insert into bookingdetails 
VALUES
(?,'2014-03-12','sl1',3,'GA',12.5,37.5),
(?,'2014-03-12','sl1',3,'GA',12.5,37.5)';
SET @a = 4;
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

If I execute above, syntax error is showing.

Comment: can u post ur syntax error?

Comment: @Sachin: You should have asked the updated query as in a new post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape single quotes around strings which are part of other strings.
You have also missed value for second parameter.

Change:

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 
'Insert into bookingdetails 
VALUES
(?,''2014-03-12'',''sl1'',3,''GA'',12.5,37.5),
(?,''2014-03-12'',''sl1'',3,''GA'',12.5,37.5)';
SET @a = 4;
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

To:

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 
'Insert into bookingdetails 
VALUES
(?,\'2014-03-12\',\'sl1\',3,\'GA\',12.5,37.5),
(?,\'2014-03-12\',\'sl1\',3,\'GA\',12.5,37.5)';
SET @a = 4;
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a, @a;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: 11:09:16 PREPARE stmt1 FROM  'Insert into bookingdetails  VALUES (?,\'2014-03-12\',\'sl1\',3,\'GA\',12.5,37.5), (?,\'2014-03-12\',\'sl1\',3,\'GA\',12.5,37.5)' 0 row(s) affected Statement prepared 0.172 sec

11:09:16 SET @a = 4 0 row(s) affected 0.172 sec

11:09:16 EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a Error Code: 1210. Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE 0.172 sec

Comment: You are missing value for second parameter. Check my answer. It has to be `execute stmt1 using @a, @a;`

Comment: @Ravinder *You are missing value for second parameter.* You were missing it too in your answer. And there is no need escape single quotes.

Comment: Yes, I added the second parameter just before you clicked *Add Comment* button. And on escape, Yes, you are right. It was my usual practice and hence it went here.

Comment: Hi guys, could you please check the updated post. I m unable to store data through PREPARE STATEMENT from stored_procedure.

Comment: @Sachin: Check one of my answers [*here, on SO, `Using prepared statements with session variables inside`*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21812237/767881).

Answer (score 2):

You have two placeholders therefore you **have to** pass two values with `USING`

```
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a, @a;
                    ^^^^^^
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36323/2)** demo

Answer (score 0):

try the below code which uses single quote

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 
'Insert into bookingdetails 
VALUES
(?,'2014-03-12','sl1',3,'GA',12.5,37.5),
(?,'2014-03-12','sl1',3,'GA',12.5,37.5)';
SET @a = 4;
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a, @a;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2014-03-12','sl1',3,'GA',12.5,37.5), (?,'2014-03-12','sl1',3,'GA',12.5,37.5)'' at line 2